# SVG Element Doesnot work in IE 9

Tags: html, svg

I have Created a circle in my `HTML` Page with following `SVG` property but works fine on `Chrome` ,`Firefox` and `IE10` as well. But it does not work in `IE version` less then 10.

```
<svg  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="height: 406px;">                   
    <g transform="translate(80,200)">
      <circle r="75" stroke-width="5" pointer-events="visible" stroke="white" fill="#F7A96B"></circle>
      <text fill="white" dx="-30" >Node 1</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(200,180)">
      <circle pointer-events="visible" r="100" stroke-width="5" stroke="white" fill="#B2CB66"></circle>
      <text fill="white" dx="-20"  >Node 2</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(380,150)">
      <circle pointer-events="visible" r="135"  stroke-width="5" stroke="white" fill="#7BBEE9"></circle>
      <text fill="white" dx="-20"  >Node 3</text>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

I cont Find any issues. Can any one help me to fix this?

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you setting on the html page?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>, This is what i am using in doctype, what i Have  to use? @RobertLongson

Comment: That's OK, so what does "does not work" mean? It doesn't display, it does display but does so incorrectly?

Comment: its Does not display in IE lower versions @RobertLongson